# ANTLR 4 casting operator takes too much

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I'm making a language and I'm having a little trouble with implementing casting in the grammer. The syntax for casting is on line 61 of the grammer file. Currently it will take something like `(Int) 5.4 + 7` and turn it into `(Int) (5.4 + 7)`. I want it to look like `((Int) 5.4) + 7`, but I haven't been able to get it to do so. Any ideas on what I need to do to fix this or where I need to go to fix it?

I stripped out the excess rules from the `grammar` file that weren't referenced by the problematic code.
[grammar file](http://pastebin.com/YZVyQxL0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I moved the 3 unary expressions into their own rule and then made casting work with either a primary or a unary expression instead of a normal expression.